# How can I see the preimage of $\overline{B_{1/2}(1)}$ under $z\mapsto z^3$ is not compact over the upper half space

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis

Let $f:\Bbb{H}\to \Bbb{C}\setminus \{0\}$ defined to be $f(z) = z^3$ ,where $\Bbb{H}$ is the upper half space, prove the preimage of the compact ball $\overline{B_{1/2}(1)}$ which center at 1,with radius $1/2$ is not compact.

I think the preimage may have intuitive geometric picture , I have no idea how to visualize it.If we write the points in $\overline{B_{1/2}(1)}$ with $\{1+\frac{r}{2}e^{2\pi i\theta}\mid r\in[0,1],\theta \in [0,1]\}$ however it's not so easy to take cubic root of $1+\frac{r}{2}e^{2\pi i\theta}$. Is there some idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the intersection of the unit circle $|z|=1$ and the closed ball $\overline{B_{1/2}(1)}.$ In particular, note that it contains the arc of the unit circle from $1$ anticlockwise to $\frac78+i\frac{\sqrt{15}}{8}.$

Show that the preimage of this arc contains points of $\Bbb H$ arbitrarily close to the real axis, so that an open cover by planes of the form $\frac{z-\overline z}{2i}>\frac1n$ for positive integers $n$ has no finite subcover.